# On sufficient condition for strong convergence in $L^{\infty}_{loc}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence $(v_n)$ of uniformly continuous functions $v_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ such that $\Big(||v_n||_{{\rm L}^{\infty}(0,1)}\Big)$ is bounded sequence. 
Is the following assertion true: If for every compact set $K\subset\subset (0,1)$ such that $\lambda(K)>0$ there exists a compact set $A\subset\subset K$ such that $\lambda(A)>0$ and such that $v_n$ is strongly pre-compact in ${\rm L}^{\infty}(A)$, then $(v_n)$ is strongly pre-compact in ${\rm L}^{\infty}_{loc}(0,1)$? I'm trying to find a sufficient condition for strong pre-compactness in ${\rm L}^{\infty}_{loc}(0,1)$ which will not use Arzela-Ascoli theorem, since I do not have equicontinuity property of $(v_n)$.

Comment: Since you added the condition $\lambda(A)>0$ the answer is no longer "obviously not; let $A$ be a singleton". I still suspect the answer is no - I don't think you're going to be able to avoid Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: I think the current question might have easy counterexamples: the sequence of hat functions $v_n(x)=\max(0,1-n|x+\tfrac 1n-\tfrac 12|)$ is not pre-compact in $L^\infty_{loc}(0,1),$ but the restriction to $(0,\tfrac 12-\epsilon)\cup (\tfrac 12+\epsilon,1)$ is pre-compact for any $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: The trouble with this example is, I think, the following: if we choose $K_{\varepsilon}:=[{1\over{2}}-\varepsilon, {1\over{2}}+\varepsilon]$, then probably it is not true that there exists compact set $A\subset\subset K_{\varepsilon}$ such that $\lambda(A)>0$ and such that $(v_n)$ is strongly pre-compact in ${\rm L}^{\infty}(A)$.

Comment: If my computation is correct, it holds that $v_n\vert_{K_{\varepsilon}}(x)\rightarrow 0$ in the pointwise sense as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. Then by Egoroff's theorem for every $0<\delta<2\varepsilon$ there exists a compact set $A_{\delta}\subset K_{\varepsilon}$ such that $\lambda(K_{\varepsilon}\backslash A_{\delta})\leq\delta$ and $v_n\vert_{A_{\delta}}(x)\rightarrow 0$ uniformly as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. So my previous comment was not true. But now I am not sure that $(v_n)$ is not strongly pre-compact in ${\rm L}^{\infty}_{loc}(0,1)$. Why such compactness fails?

Comment: Still, since the converse of Arzela-Ascoli theorem is true (see http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-converse-of-the-arzela-ascoli-theorem
) I guess it all comes down to equicontinutiy as both necessary and sufficient condition. So if $(v_n)$  defined above are not equi-continuous, then this example is indeed a proper counterexample for the initial assertion.